# Call Method Or Iterate over Array in HTML with JSX

Tags: javascript, node.js, reactjs, html-email

I am running into a problem I have never had before, its honestly the first time I have had to write something along these lines and a solution seems to escape me.

I am using SendGrid to send an HTML email via a POST in express on Node. This works perfectly fine up until I need to iterate over items in the cart to customize the HTML and reflect each item.

Currently, in the HTML, I can print a variable by calling the `${req.body.data.item_name}`
This works great but at `${req.body.data.cart}` is an array of items they just purchased.
For UIX I would like to display a list of all the items purchased with the price and quantity.

One way I have tried this is by writing a helper function:

```
function iterateItems(cart){
let body = ""

cart.forEach(function(item) {
      body = body + `<p style="Margin-top: 20px;Margin-bottom: 0;">${item.name}: $${item.price} QTY: ${item.qty}</p>`
    })
}
```

Then in the HTML text tried calling it with `${this.iterateItems(req.body.data.cart)}`

It comes back as undefined and I honestly kind of expected that. I'm curious whats the best way to approach this and get it to work.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The function you created returns undefined because it doesn't `return`'s anything. You can try this:

```
function iterateItems(cart){
   let body = ""

   cart.forEach(function(item) {
      body = body + `<p style="Margin-top: 20px;Margin-bottom: 0;">${item.name}: $${item.price} QTY: ${item.qty}</p>`
   })
   return body;
}
```

Hope this works for you.

Comment: Thank you! hahah Sometimes its something so simple, I swear its simply because I was working for 12+ hrs straight hahah

Answer (score 0):

Try using map instead of foreach , should fix the issue